# box2dlights set scale from box2d

Tags: java, opengl, box2d, libgdx, scaling

I'm making a game in libGDX and I decided to use box2dlights to render the lights. I did not used cameras so much up to this point, because I already had most of the code done in pure LWJGL. There are two main operations that I need to do with the coordinates of everything.

The first is to translate the screen to the position of the map (the map is bigger than the screen, and the position of the player defines what portion of the map is visible). So for example, if the player is at (50, 30), I translate everything by (-50, -30), so that the player is in the middle.

The second thing is to multiply everything by a constant, that is the conversion from box2d meters to pixels on screen.

However, since I do not have access to box2dlights rendering, I need to pass these two information to the ray handler, and the only way to do that is via Camera. So I created an Orthographic Camera and translate it in deltaS every tick before drawing, instead of manually subtracting deltaS from every coordinate. That part works perfectly. On the other hand, the zoom thingy does not seem to work, because it zooms in and out based in the middle of the screen. For example, if I set zoom = 2, the screen is reduced twice, but it is centered on the screen. The coordinate (0,0) is not (0,0), as I would expect, but instead is screen.width/4.

Is there any way to set the camera so that it multiplies every coordinate by a number, you would assume zoom function should do OR is there any way to do it directly on box2dlights?
I don't know if my problem is very clear or common, but I can't find anything anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out! The problem was that I needed to set the zoom **before** I used

```
camera.setToOrtho(true, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
```

Because that method uses the current zoom to set its properties. Hope this helps!